# CSS is not applied to row chart

Tags: css, angular, dc.js

I'm trying to hide the axis on my row chart. Just like this problem [Hide dc.js chart x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030240/hide-dc-js-chart-x-axis). But I couldn't modify the  styling no matter what I do.

When I tried using 
`#your-row-chart svg g g.axis.x { display: none; }`, but its not applied to my chart.

This is my css
`div.dc-chart.sampleId.scrolled-row-chart svg g g.axis { display: none; }`
Not sure what is my mistake. It works fine till `div.dc-chart.sampleId.scrolled-row-chart` which modify the style of my row chart.

Below is the expected result. I remove the styling by manually editing the css on Chrome. I even copy the HTML selector to the css to make sure I'm pointing to the correct element, but it still doesn't work.

[image: rowchart]

Comment: Please create a MCV, [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for posting an answer to a duplicate question. I know it is against site rules but I think it helps people's google searches, and I am trying to combat the FUD of "I found an answer but it didn't work for me".

As others have commented, it's hard to test without a running example. So I started with [the basic row chart example](http://127.0.0.1:8888/web/examples/row.html).

I tried adding the CSS

```
.dc-chart#test svg g g.axis { display: none; }
```

and it worked fine. Maybe your CSS selector is too specific!

I also tried

```
chart.margins({left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0});
```

and this also worked!

Screen shot with no axis, just to make my sad duplicate answer more interesting:

[image: no axis]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to edit SVG directly? If it isn't possible, then check if your styles are on higher layer than the ones you want to override (http://qnimate.com/dive-into-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ::ng-deep prefix in your css